# Removing a sequence of characters from strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, string

In rails I simply want to remove 'http://' or 'https://' from a string if they are present.  Currently I'm achieving this with the below code:

```
install_url.delete('http://').delete('https://')
```

I feel like this might not be the best way to do it.  Are there any better suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
install_url.sub(/^http[s]?:\/\//, '')
```

Comment: This was perfect. I need to look into regex more.  Any good resources you recommend?

Comment: You can start here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html the good thing about regular expressions is that they are universal, you can use them on ruby, perl, php, python, java, etc.

Comment: That's great!  I also do a lot of Java and Objective-C dev so it will be useful to learn more about.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
install_url.gsub(/https?:\/\//, '')
```